# How to Call a javascript function after SAjaxsource completes in JQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using JQuery SAjaxsource How can i Call a javascript function after SAjaxsource completes. I want to update a div after the completion of the datatable load.Please help me...

Edit:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
                var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {

                    "bServerSide": true,
                                    "sSearch":false,
                                    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
                                    "bPaginate": true,
                                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                                    "sAjaxSource": "server_processingCDB1.php"
                } );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://datatables.net/ref#fnDrawCallback also works for this, and saved you needing to override fnServerData.

> **Parameter:**    fnDrawCallback
>
> **Type:** function
>
> **Inputs:**   {object}: DataTables settings object
>
> This function is called on every 'draw' event, and allows you to
>   dynamically modify any aspect you want about the created DOM.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
      alert( 'DataTables has redrawn the table' );
    }
  } );
} );
```

Comment: This is an imperfect solution; it gets called on page load when the table is drawn without data, and then called again as soon as the data loads which may be less then ideal depending on your desire.

Comment: It would call before rendering data.

Answer (score 8):

take a look at the fnServerData option in the callbacks section of the help -> http://www.datatables.net/usage/callbacks

Gives you everything you need ... here some example code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "../examples_support/server_processing.php",
        "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
            $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) { 
                /* Do whatever additional processing you want on the callback, then tell DataTables */
                fnCallback(json)
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: sorry, i edited my question. how can i call a javascript function or how can i update a div

Comment: I want to make it work even though, I don't provide any file path for 
"sAjaxSource". Can you please tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

For datatables version 1.10.12

```
$('#table_id').dataTable({
  ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/your/url',
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      success:function(data){
        callback(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#listingData').dataTable({
    "sAjaxSource": "youAjaxSource.php",
    "fnDrawCallback": function (aoData) {
       response = aoData.jqXHR.responseJSON;
       console.log(response);
    }
});
```

For reload via fnReloadAjax

```
 $('#listingData').dataTable().fnReloadAjax("youAjaxSource.php", function (json) {
      console.log(json);
  });
```